# how to read this xml in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having xml as result for webservice api . i need to parse the result and update to database table. my xml is below . it is a response text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<double>1</double>
```

Sqlserver 2008 Code :

```
    declare @xml xml, @rate DECIMAL(10,4)
  set @xml=REPLACE(@ResponseText ,'encoding="utf-8"','')
  select @rate= @xml.value('(/double)[1]','decimal')
```

I want to get the value of double but it always return the null .

Please help me out .

Hi , have Done changes as per your suggestion still no getting.

```
 declare @xml XML
 DECLARE @responsetext VARCHAR(900)

 declare @rate DECIMAL(10,4)
 SET @responsetext = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <double xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">1</double>'
 set @xml=REPLACE(@ResponseText ,'encoding="utf-8"','')
 select @rate= @xml.value('(/double)[1]','decimal')
 select @rate
```

Comment: I tried a variant on your code and I got a 1, not a NULL. Are you certain that is the XML being fed into `@ResponseText`? Try a `PRINT @ResponseText` before that to verify. How are you populating `@ResponseText`?

Comment: Did my suggestion work? If so could you please mark my answer as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @X XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<double xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">1</double>'

SELECT @X.value ('declare namespace x="http://www.webserviceX.NET/"; (/x:double)[1]', 'decimal')
```

Updated to reflect your use of namespace; the general point is that you don't need to do string manipulation to make this work.  The  header is fully supported.  However, namespaces are important.

Comment: Done; namespaces change things :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the namespace when querying using the value() Method.

Change the first parameter of value() from

```
'(/double)[1]'
```

to

```
'declare namespace x="http://www.webserviceX.NET/"; (/x:double)[1]'
```

So the full example will look like this

```
declare @xml XML
 DECLARE @responsetext VARCHAR(900)

 declare @rate DECIMAL(10,4)
 SET @responsetext = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <double xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">1</double>'
 set @xml=REPLACE(@ResponseText ,'encoding="utf-8"','')
 select @rate= @xml.value('declare namespace x="http://www.webserviceX.NET/"; (/x:double)[1]','decimal')
 select @rate
```

which should return 1.000 (decimal)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just some sample code - this returns a 1, not a NULL:

```
declare @xml xml,        @rate DECIMAL(10,4)
declare @ResponseText varchar(900)

set @ResponseText = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <double>1</double>'

set @xml=REPLACE(@ResponseText ,'encoding="utf-8"','')
select @rate= @xml.value('(/double)[1]','decimal')
select @rate
```

Comment: hi nick , i have updated the code . but still facing same issue. Changes of code done above

Comment: No. Your original XML sample did not contain `xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/"`. If you leave that in you get NULL. If you take it out you get 1. If you follow Sveins advice, you can leave it in and you'll get 1. Svein has the answer. In future post all the code.